# How to validate textbox's value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

Here is the code. There are two different files

**1 metadata.php**

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#addAuthor").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({url:"n.php",type: "POST",data: ({id: '1'}),success:function(result){
         $("#div1").append(result);
            }});
        });

        $("#removeAuthor").click(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               var lastNode = $("#div1").children().last();
               lastNode.prev().remove();
               lastNode.remove();
         });
      });
 </script>

  <div id="div1" >

  </div>
       <button id="addAuthor" >Add Author</button>
      <button id="removeAuthor">Remove Author</button>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save & Continue">
```

**2 n.php**

```
Name:<input type="text" name="txtname[]">
age:<input type="text" name="txtage[]">
```

Now what happens on the click of 'addAuthor' butoon ajax loads all the content of n.php as many times as button clicks.

And txtname[] and txtage[] will store all the textbox's value.
But these arrays will give values on the form post.

So how can i validate textbox's value before form post?
Because If I validate values on form post,and if validation fails then metadata.php will not remain with n.php 's loaded content.

So how can i do this??

Comment: How you set data array for **txtname** and **txtage** ? with php? can show this?

Comment: How does you n.php - code look like? I'm not sure you should use arrays of txtname and txtage

Answer (score 0):

If you mean validating txtname and txtage before submitting the form, you can do this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#div1 input[name='txtname']").each(function() {
            // make test on the current txtname
        });

        $("#div1 input[name='txtage']").each(function() {
            // make test on the current txtage
        });

        // uncomment this to prevent form submition
        //return false;
    });
</script>
```